# Recover BLOWERIO_URL

Tags: heroku, sms-gateway

Say my fat fingers managed to set my BLOWERIO_URL to something invalid:

```
$ heroku config:set BLOWERIO_URL=https://{user:pass}@api.blower.io/ --app recon-trac
```

How can I recover the correct, working BLOWERIO_URL?

I haven't been able to find any troubleshooting guides in Heroku's so-called "support" section, and Google isn't much help either.

I'm getting "400 Bad Request" when I try to send an SMS. It was broken earlier, and I fixed it by changing the BLOWERIO_URL, and now it's broken again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command to open a control panel for Blower.io:

```
heroku addons:open blowerio --app your-app-name
```

Clicking on the Send SMS tab will show you a command you can use to test. The command includes the URL:

```
curl -X POST -d "to=+14155550000&message=This is a test from Blower.io" -H "Accept: application/json" https://12345678-9abc-def0-1234-56789abcdef0:a1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8i9J0k1@api.blower.io/messages
```

You want to copy everything from **https** to the end, except **messages**.

```
https://12345678-9abc-def0-1234-56789abcdef0:a1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8i9J0k1@api.blower.io/
```

Now you can set your Heroku BLOWERIO_URL appropriately:

```
heroku config:set BLOWERIO_URL=https://12345678-9abc-def0-1234-56789abcdef0:a1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8i9J0k1@api.blower.io/ --app your-app-name
```

Thanks to Glenn Gillen from Blower.io Support for getting me straightened out.